# Why won't my spreadsheet accept formula with "&"

Tags: microsoft-excel

My excel spreadsheet won't accept a formula with the "&" in it. For example =A1+A2&" OK" and if A1=1 and A2=2 then the result should be 3 OK.
This same formula works in another spreadsheet but in the spreadsheet I am work on it gives the result VALUE.
Why does it work in one spreadsheet but not another?

Comment: This formula works fine. What EXACTLY is in the cells that you have the problem with?

Comment: Basically the #VALUE error occurs when any value/data in literally a Text instead of Number,,so better share the Screen shot with us!!

Comment: you can always evaluate your formula (formulas tab - evaluate formula) to see how Excel interprets your formula and understand which exact step fails.

Comment: If possible, you'd better provide the sample about another problem sheet.

Answer (score 2):

Check that A1 and A2 contain numbers, not text.

The **#Value!** error occurs when the operator `+` is used with text values. It even survives numbers stored as text, but if you feed it words, then it throws an error.

The `&` operator is innocent.

Answer (score 0):

The **#VALUE!** error appears when either cell/cells are left blank, or when literally the Formula encounters Text value instead of Number, or when Date is evaluated as Text by the Formula.

- To fix the **#VALUE!** error, enter correct value.

**Check examples below:**

[image]

- The used Formula is `=A1+A2&" OK"`
- You get **#VALUE** error, if & when any of the values is literally a Text (string).

[image]

- To fix this issue (when one of the values is literally Text), you can use this Formula.

  `=SUM(A1,A2)&" OK"`
- Or, even this Array Formula will works also.

`{=SUM(IF(ISERROR(A1:A2),"",A1:A2))&" Ok"}`

**N.B.** Finish an Array Formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**.

[image]

**This Formula `=A1+A2&" Ok"` will works also, even when both Cells has data as `TEXT`.**

[image]

*You may adjust cell references in Formula as needed.*